# app getting crashed when trying to use setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android

main activity

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void button(View v)
{
    FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
    frag1 f1=new frag1();
    f1.show(fragmentManager,"TAG");
}
}
```

fragment

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class frag1 extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener{
Button button;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1,container,false);


}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    button= (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) getActivity());

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"working",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


}
```

This is a code for a simple dialog box.

Here's a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T568mtL9fys) where I learnt it from. It works completely fine if I just create the dialog box with calling the button.

Comment: what are your logs saying?

Comment: instead of     button.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) getActivity()); just write     button.setOnClickListener(this);

Answer (score 0):

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1,container,false);
    button= (Button) View.findViewById(R.id.button);

    button..setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
     {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
         {
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"working",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
     });
    return view;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your line from

```
button.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) getActivity());
```

to

```
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Also, use

```
getSupportFragmentManager() to instead of getFragmentManager()
```

and import

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```